# How To Slide One Image Out From Behind Another On Hover?

Tags: css, image, hover, slide

I'm trying to create an effect where an LP record (we'll call it the background image) slides out from behind a record sleeve (foreground image). I'd like to do this with as much CSS as possible, however I understand that having the LP slide in and out smoothly will require JQuery. The foreground image completely obscures the background image and I can't figure out how to move the background image move when hovering over the foreground image. I also want both images to be anchors if possible. Hopefully that's clear(ish)! If anyone could help me out I'd be extremely grateful, thanks!

Here's what im working with so far

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="Record.png" width="200" height="200" id="record"/>
  <img src="Sleeve.png" width="200" height="200" id="sleeve" />
</div>

<!--CSS-->
#container {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

#record {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sleeve {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks all for the answers, I'm trying to use the one given in the first [comment](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wuPmT/) to this post, but I can't for the life of me get it to work myself! Could anyone help me see where I'm going wrong? Thanks again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testing.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="container">
  <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/oldschool_babasse/Png/Hardware/CD%20oldSchool.png" width="200" height="200" id="record"/>
  <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Box_Grey.png" width="200" height="200" id="sleeve" />
</div>​

<script>

$('#container').hover(function() {
    var record = $('img:eq(0)', this);
    record.stop(1,0).animate({
        left: '200px'
    }, 1000, function() {
        record.css('z-index', 11).stop(1, 0).animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 1000);
    });
}, function() {
    var record = $('img:eq(0)', this);
    record.stop(1,0).animate({
        left: '200px'
    }, 1000, function() {
        record.css('z-index', 1).stop(1, 0).animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 1000);
    });
});​

</script>

</body>
</html>

<!--CSS-->

#container {
    width: 400px;
    height:200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:auto;
}

#record {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sleeve {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
}​
```

Comment: Something along the lines of this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wuPmT/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it purely with css by adding this to your existing code:

```
#record {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease-out; 
     -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease-out; 
      -ms-transition: left 0.5s ease-out; 
       -o-transition: left 0.5s ease-out; 
          transition: left 0.5s ease-out;
}

#container:hover #record {
    left: 100px;  /* This is assuming you want it to slide from left-to-right */
}
```

Unfortunately, the animation will only work in newer browsers.  Older browsers will just show the record popping in/out, which may or may not be a horrible effect.

If you want it to work in all browsers, you'll need to do the animation with some javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:

```
$("#sleeve").hover(
    function(){
       $("#record").animate({left: '+=100',bottom: '+=100'}, 1750);
    },
    function(){
       $("#record").animate({left: '-=100',bottom: '-=100'}, 1750);  
    });
```

On hover the record slides out, if the mouse leaves the sleeve it slides back. What you want to have exactly you have to code on your own.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rniestroj/nZhbg/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Generally, we like users to post code they've tried before just asking us for the answer, but here's something to get you started with hover:

```
$("selector").hover(function(){
  //do some code on hover
});
```

And with animation:

```
$("selector").animate({
  //animate to these values
  left:250px,
});
```

Perhaps look at these docs for [animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

You may be able to do this with CSS3 animation, but I've given you jQuery that will have cross browser support, and enable you to do more complicated stuff if you would like.